# Q&A: Which options do we have to overcome the cost of NFT emission (minting)?

Tags: nft, ethereum-classic

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

I have to explore alternatives to mint NFT at public ethereum chain because of the cost of minting a token makes the project unprofitable. Which options do we have to overcome the cost of NFT emission (minting)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are such things like lazy minting and gas-free minting. The first one postpone writing a NFT on the ledger till it would be purchased. The second one write NFT on the ledger at the beginning without gas and unclear logic behind it.

Another option might be deploying own ledger within the community where all generated ether goes to the community operations. (is it possible even in this case to face the lack of ether to run operations?). It also can be configured to use zero cost of gas on all operations.

Finally, we have to optimize contract for decreasing the cost of mining a token:
“One of the more substantial gains you can achieve is through eliminating the Enumerable extension. Considering all Transfer events are indexed and easily retrievable, it's not a significant loss.”

One more thing like gas relay provider or gas station network:
https://docs.opengsn.org/#the-problem